# Extjs input is hidden on focus by ipad virtual keyboard

Tags: ios, ipad, extjs, virtual-keyboard

I have an EXTJS (4.0.7) web application that i had to wrap to work as an iPad app (ios 9.1).
The screen is divided with a border layout, but whenever i click a text field the virtual keyboard goes up and the south region of the app goes completely out of place (see picture).
This seems to be a well IOS know bug, but all the fixes that ive found are to smaller apps/frameworks in which you have complete control over html/css.
The solution usually involves adding listeners(focus/blur) to the text fields so that whenever the keyboard shows the css of the footer/south-region is changed.
I added an Override that always get called whenever the text field gains focus/blur but i dont know what i have to do to fix the problem.

```
Ext.require('Ext.form.field.Text', function () {
// fix for shell south region when input gains focus triggering virtual keyboard
    if (Ext.is.iPad) {
        var keyboardFix= {
            onFocus: function () {
                //TODO keyboardFix
                this.callParent();
            },
            onBlur: function () {
                //TODO remove keyboardFix
                this.callParent();
            }
        }

        Ext.form.field.Text.override(keyboardFix);
    }
});
```

[image: input hidden by virtual keyboard]

Comment: were you able to fight this?

Comment: i've justed added the answer

Answer (score 1):

The entire application was getting resized and it was breaking the layout, so, if you detect that the app is running on a iPad you stop the window resizing event.
Put this in a override javascript file:

```
Ext.onReady(function() {
    Ext.EventManager.onWindowResize(function () {
        if(Ext.is.iPad){
            return false;
        }
    });
});
```